# How to chang lookup array in autocomplete plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have initialized autocomplete by providing initial lookup array but now I want to change lookup array.

```
$('#abc').autocomplete({
            // serviceUrl: '/autosuggest/service/url',
            lookup: original_head_array,
            lookupFilter: function(suggestion, originalQuery, queryLowerCase) {
                var re = new RegExp('\\b' + $.Autocomplete.utils.escapeRegExChars(queryLowerCase), 'gi');
                return re.test(suggestion.value);
            },
            onSelect: function(suggestion) { }
});
```

In above code, key value array given in lookup, having name original_head_array. i want to change that after user enter a new option. i.e there is list of countries suggested in autocomplete but now user added new country Nigeria, now suggestion should include Nigeria as well in auto complete plugin.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some hard research, I got answer of my question. it can be achieved from that.

```
var myObject = new Object();

        var tp=[];
        tp.push({
            data:   "4",
            value: "Nigeria"
        });
        myObject.lookup = tp;
        $('#'+headid+'').autocomplete().setOptions(myObject);
```